# Client-Server communication Internet connection issue

Tags: android, networking, client-server

I am working on client-server communication.
In my laptop, I installed server and my laptop was connected to public wifi at the company.
(I am working at the company as an internship)

But, the public wifi is not connected to my laptop anymore I don't know why and I used wire line in my office. When I used public wifi, and if I send information such as name, photo to the server it worked. But, when I connected wire to my laptop, it's not working. 
I tried at my home with wifi at home, it works properly.

I don't know why it's not working when I use company's internet wire.
when I click save (then it would send to server), the app doesn't work, just stops.
I think it's network problem for sure.

The log file says:

```
dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 305K, 13% free 21555K/24775K, paused 19ms
log_tag  1312331231.jpg
dalvikvm GC_CURRENT freed 1195K, 10% free 22408K/24775K, paused 2ms+4ms
dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 837K, 9% free 22458K/24775K, paused 19ms
dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1116K, 10% free 22458K/24775K, paused 28ms
```

And so on...

Any advice?

Comment: why this problem is not good enough to post???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some firewall its blocking your service.

Comment: what ports are you using on your server?